# Prestashop 1.7 products per page dropdown list in category

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am looking through Prestashop 1.7 and i want to overide the controller responsible for Products Listing ( aka Category Archive ).
I am using the official Prestashop starter theme and i want to override the controller in order to get some more data to the sort-order.tpl

```
<div class="products-sort-order">
  <span>{if isset($listing.sort_selected)}{$listing.sort_selected}{else}{l s='Sort by:' d='Shop.Theme.Global'}{/if}</span>
  {foreach from=$sort_orders item=sort_order}
    <a
      class="{['current' => $sort_order.current, 'js-search-link' => true]|classnames}"
      href="{$sort_order.url}"
      rel="nofollow"
    >
      {$sort_order.label}
    </a>
  {/foreach}
</div>
```

In the above snippet there is a sort_order variable , part of a $listing variable comming from  products-top.tpl

```
<div id="js-product-list-top" class="products-selection">
  {if $listing.pagination.total_items|count > 1}
    <p>{l s='There are %product_count% products.' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog' sprintf=['%product_count%' => $listing.pagination.total_items|count]}</p>
  {elseif $listing.pagination.total_items > 0}
    <p>{l s='There is 1 product.' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</p>
  {/if}

  {block name='sort_by'}
    {include file='catalog/_partials/sort-orders.tpl' sort_orders=$listing.sort_orders}
  {/block}

  {block name='pagination_summary'}
    {l s='Showing %from%-%to% of %total% item(s)' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog' sprintf=[
    '%from%' => $listing.pagination.items_shown_from ,
    '%to%' => $listing.pagination.items_shown_to,
    '%total%' => $listing.pagination.total_items
    ]}
  {/block}
</div>
```

My goal is to override the responsible controller in order to generate some links to alter the resultsPerPage just like the $sort_order changes the listing order passing some parameters to the url.
The problem is that althought i've search nearly all controllers , i did not find the one passing those data to the tpl.
Due to the lack of proper documentation i am asking for a bit of "where-is-that" information from a more experienced dev 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, create an override for classes/controller/ProductListingFrontController.php

and change line 279:

```
$resultsPerPage <= 0 || $resultsPerPage > 36
```

to (for example..)

```
$resultsPerPage <= 0 || $resultsPerPage > 100
```

100 in this example is the max number of items you want per page. You can also choose more or less, depending what you want. Now let's alter your .tpl

In your theme, go to themes/yourtheme/templates/catalog/_partials/sort-orders.tpl

On the top of the page (right underneath the licence) add this to assign the variables:

```
{if !empty($smarty.get.order)}
        {capture assign='ordering'}order={$smarty.get.order}&amp;{/capture}
    {else}
        {assign var='ordering' value=''}
    {/if}

    {if !empty($smarty.get.resultsPerPage)}
        {assign var='results_per_page' value=$smarty.get.resultsPerPage}
    {else}
        {assign var='results_per_page' value=25}
    {/if}
```

And now, right underneath, add this code:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <label style="float:left;margin-right: 15px" class="form-control-label hidden-sm-down sort-label">{l s='Products per page:'}</label>
  <div style="float:left;" class="sort-select dropdown js-dropdown">
    <a class="custom-select select-title" rel="nofollow" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        {$results_per_page}
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a rel="nofollow" href="?{$ordering}resultsPerPage=25" class="dropdown-item js-search-link">
            25
        </a>
      <a rel="nofollow" href="?{$ordering}resultsPerPage=50" class="dropdown-item js-search-link">
            50
        </a>
      <a rel="nofollow" href="?{$ordering}resultsPerPage=75" class="dropdown-item js-search-link">
            75
        </a>
      <a rel="nofollow" href="?{$ordering}resultsPerPage=100" class="dropdown-item js-search-link">
            100
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You might need to change the layout (or the number of items, or the max results per page...) but you'll be good to go :)

If you're going to change the number of items (in the dropdown) for example, just change:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="?{$ordering}resultsPerPage=25"
```

to

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="?{$ordering}resultsPerPage=40"
```

To adjust the amount of products per page.

Comment: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/controller/ProductListingFrontController.php , i've already search the file , to be more specific i've tried to alter the 'listing' at 515 line, with no luck.

Comment: If i understand your question rght, you want the customer to be able to select the amount of products per page (like in a dropdown select field for example)?

Comment: Yes exactly, but i want to implement it by my own and not use a module, i figured oute how to construct the urls , i cant figure thought how to pass it to the view. A dont want to pass data thought an irrelevant controller like FrontController

Comment: I've been testing for you. I'll be posting a new awnser shortly

Comment: And there you go, tested and working :) Hope you're happy

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry for the delay that definitely did the trick!

Comment: I want to make this selection permanent for user to remember his choice throw all session. How this is possible? I think it's quite expected behavior for this selection box

Comment: This works great. There is just one thing I changed. Instead of setting the results_per_page to a fixed number in the template I use the number set in the admin. For the dropdown I just multiply this number. In this way this field in the admin still has meaning.

So instead of `{assign var='results_per_page' value='25'}` I use `{assign var='results_per_page' value={Configuration::get('PS_PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE')}}` and in the link I use `{Configuration::get('PS_PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE') * 2}` and so on.